# Doctrine 2 entity hydrator

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, entity

Is there way to hydrate entity data like as after doctrine query

```
$entityData = $this->entityService->find($id)->getArrayResult();
```

and do it if you already have entity

```
$entity = $this->entityService->find($id)->getOneOrNullResult();
$entityData = $SomeDoctrineService->entityToArray($entity);
```

**Solution**

Firstly you can use \DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject

```
$hydrator = DoctrineObject(
        $entityManager,
        get_class($entity)
    );

$entityData = $hydrator->extract($entity);
```

and secondly I've added custom hydrator trait EntityDataTrait

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\Proxy;
trait EntityDataTrait
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        $data = get_object_vars($this);

        if ($this instanceof Proxy) {
            $originClassName = get_parent_class($this);

            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (!property_exists($originClassName, $key)) {
                    unset ($data[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            if (method_exists($this, 'get' . ucfirst($key))) {
                $data[$key] = $this->{'get' . ucfirst($key)}();
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
}
```

for example

```
class MyEntity {
  use EntityDataTrait;

  /*properties and methods below*/
}

$entity = new MyEntity();
$entityData = $entity->toArray();
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer rather than part of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no built in doctrine functionality for this. You should create your own serializer or use one of existent ones: JMS Serializer, Symfony Serializer.

You can create your own serializer as well. Sample code could be found here [Doctrine2 export entity to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507300/doctrine2-export-entity-to-array/13522452) but it was mentioned that it is not the best approach.